# Unable to run Rodeo IDE with python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, rodeo

I have installed Rodeo on my Ubuntu 18.04 system and with python 2.7 it runs fine.

When I try to run python3 in Rodeo IDE I am getting the error message that says "Jupyter is not installed" even though it should be.

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: might be worth noting that Rodeo [appears to have been abandoned by its developers due to aquisition](https://github.com/yhat/rodeo/issues/655)

Comment: ah thanks for the info, wasn't aware of that